# How to check whether a value exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server

we have a table (sales plan form MDS) like

```
> 20171201 2017 12 2.155.125 ...some other values 
> 20171101 2017 11 2.155.125 ...some other values
```

and I want to check wheter a record for current month exists (say 2018/01).

I've tried:

```
IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            spc.DateID
        FROM
            dim.SalesPlanCountry spc
            JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON spc.DateID = cal.DateID
        WHERE
            cal.CalendarYear = @Year
            AND cal.MonthOfYear = @Month
    ) THEN 
        SELECT 'OK'
    ELSE SELECT 'Missing'
```

which returns

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all delete `THEN` keyword, you don't need it

Comment: @Valerica That was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said you don't need the `THEN` keyword, just use `SELECT <values>` or use a `CASE WHEN` statement (see **phoniq** answer)

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT
        spc.DateID
    FROM dim.SalesPlanCountry spc
    JOIN dim.Calendar cal
        ON spc.DateID = cal.DateID
    WHERE cal.CalendarYear = @Year
        AND cal.MonthOfYear = @Month
)
SELECT 'OK'
ELSE 
SELECT 'Missing'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN spc.DateID = NULL THEN 'OK' ELSE 'Missing' END
FROM
  dim.SalesPlanCountry spc
  JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON spc.DateID = cal.DateID
WHERE
  cal.CalendarYear = @Year
  AND cal.MonthOfYear = @Month
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please [edit] your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22039459)

Answer (score 0):

Could this not be simplified down to...

```
SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN 'Missing' ELSE 'OK' END
FROM dim.SalesPlanCountry spc
     JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON spc.DateID = cal.DateID
WHERE cal.CalendarYear = @Year
  AND cal.MonthOfYear = @Month;
```

No need for an `EXISTS`. When doing a `COUNT` of a dataset, a value will always be returned, even if the data set returns no rows.